# What is needed for a game's stats to be saved?

Tags: battlefield-3

Last night I played a few games with my friend. While in the last game, I suddenly remembered something I had to do and was about to leave but my friend told me that I would lose my progress if I did so. I stayed until the end, through the scoreboard screen and quit while the next map was loading. Taking a look [at my profile](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/user/Xeon06/) now, I can't see any of yesterday's games. I don't remember how much XP I had yesterday so there is no sure way for me to check that. I had gotten a dozen ribbon and I don't see them in the feed, but there could be specific conditions to be showing them.

My questions then.

1. If you quit a game early, do you lose progress / XP?
2. What if you quit on the scoreboard? Do you need to wait for the next map to load to save your progress?
3. Any idea why the games aren't showing up? Some of them I definitely waited for the next map to load. Is there a delay for them to be shown on Battlelog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you quit a game early you will not lose any progress. The only reason you'll ever lose progress, is if your game crashes, and even then, it saves most of the time.

Sometimes battlelog screws up and won't show any of your recent games (this has happened to me for 2 days at one point). You're stats will all update and everything will be current, you just can't see any of your battle reports or any of your new unlocks in your feed.

Comment: I guess however you will miss out of Ribbons like the Conquest/Rush Ribbon and Conquest/Rush Win Ribbon.